# I want to run my Outlook Addin on selecitng multiple emails in Outlook web client, however the Office.context.mailbox.item is undefined

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Addin that is working all fine for a single email, however I want to enable the Addin to work when selecting multiple emails. This seems to work in Outlook Desktop client and I can get the context of multiple email. The `Office.context.mailbox.item` is undefined for the Addin in Outlook Web, but it has value in the Desktop client i.e., the `itemId` of the first selected email.

Does the multiple select capability available for Outlook Web client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the multi-select feature is supported everywhere where the requirement set 1.13 is supported. Make sure that you deal with the modern Outlook UI when connected to Exchange Online.

Support for the item multi-select feature was introduced in requirement set 1.13. See [clients and platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets#requirement-sets-supported-by-exchange-servers-and-outlook-clients) that support this requirement set.

Read more about that feature in the [Activate your Outlook add-in on multiple messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/item-multi-select) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve selected items using the following method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getSelectedItemsAsync(asyncResult => {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      resolve(asyncResult.value);
    } else {
      reject(asyncResult.error);
    }
  });
```

For more details on each selected email, you can utilize the following method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getMailRequest(mailId), (result) => {
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            resolve(result.value);
          } else {
            console.log(result.error);
            reject(result.error);
          }
        });
```

Here is the getMailRequest function:

```
getMailRequest(itemId: string) {
return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
           <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
</soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
      <t:ItemId Id="${itemId}"/>
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`;
```

}